# Define a convex set in a linear space $X$. Show that the open ball $ B(0, δ) $ is a convex set in a linear space $ \Bbb R^n $ over $ \Bbb R $.

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I know that a convex set in a linear space $X$ is defined thus:

Let $ X $ be a real linear space. A set $ E ⊂ X $ is said to be convex if and only if for each pair of points $ x, y ∈ E $, the line segment joining $ x $ and $ y $ lies in $ E $, i.e. if $ x, y ∈ E $, then 
$$ L [x, y] = \{z \in X\ :\ z = (1 - λ)x + λy, λ ∈ [0, 1]\} ⊂ E. $$

Now, the problem I have is this: How can I make use of the definition above to show that the open ball $ B(0, δ) $ is a convex set in a linear space $ \Bbb R^n $ over $ \Bbb R $.

Source: MTH 303 - Advanced Calculus/OAU - Harmattan Semester Examinations/2017 - 2018 Academic Session/Convex Set/Q1. (b)

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Comment: You all contribution did help a lot. Your answers did not only show me how an open ball $ B(0, δ) $ is as a convex set, but it did give me a deeper meaning as to what an open ball really is in definition and notation. Thanks, I really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|x\|<\delta, \|y\|<\delta$ and  $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$ then $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\| \leq \lambda \|x\|+(1-\lambda)\|y\| <\delta (\lambda +1-\lambda) =\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x, y\in B(0, \delta)$, and let $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

If you can prove that $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y \in B(0,\delta)$, then you have proven that $B(0,\delta)$ is convex. You can prove this easily using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way you can show me how that can be accomplished @5xum

Comment: Thanks for the triangle inequality concept, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Is $x,y\in B(0,\delta)$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$, then$$\bigl\lVert(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\bigr\rVert\leqslant(1-\lambda)\lVert x\rVert+\lambda\lVert y\rVert<(1-\lambda)\delta+\lambda\delta=\delta$$and therefore $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\in B(0,\delta)$.